# GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo - Method not found in SPWeb

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a web part that contains the below code:

```
SPPermissionInfo info = site.RootWeb.GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
```

It compiles on a co-workers environment, runs on his environment, but when deployed to the production environment error throws a runtime error. Both environments are SP2.

Environment: SharePoint 2007 SP2, Windows Server 2008

Comment: Self-answering - the issue was that cumulative updates were applied to the development environment, but not production. There are method calls around permissions that are not in SP2, but are included in the August 2009 CU.

Comment: BTW: It's perfectly fine to answer and accept your own question.

Comment: @Stefan - I wasn't able to answer, as my rep was so low. I tried that first :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo()` method was initially not present but later added in an update. Kindly install latest updates for sharePoint.